# Add text on line

Tags: keynote, text

I'm trying to add some text on a connection line. And when I move the connected shape, the text will move with the line.

How can I bind the text to the line?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried selecting the objects and grouping them? (Hold shift while selecting the objects and then, once the ones you want to lock together are selected, press Option + Command + G)

Comment: This works, but if I just group line and text, the line will lose its connection to   other two shapes. I need group all of them.

Comment: Then use shift to select all of them and then group them

Comment: So it's impossible to just group line and text and retain the connection to other shapes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is currently not possible whilst keeping the connection line attached to the other shapes. To keep the text associated with the line, you can group them together, but then the connection line isn't fixed to the shapes any more.

It is possible to group the connected shapes, line and text all together, such that you can move the whole group as one, however this doesn't work for your example where you only move one of the shapes and want the text to move too.

You can provide feedback to Apple here:

- https://www.apple.com/feedback/keynote.html

Answer (score 1):

You can create a connected figure with some text on a line. The trick is to make the line really two lines, and to join them end-to-end on the narrow center of the double arrow shape.

Plan:

1. Create a textual label that floats to the side of a connection point.
2. Connect two vertical lines from that connection point to one shape above and another shape below. The two lines make an imperceptible 180-degree joint at the connection point. The result is a connected figure that appears to be one labeled line.
3. If you don't want your labeled line to be vertical, you can rotate the connection point.

Details:

1. Create the textual label:

   - Press the plus, which acts as an Add menu. Choose the shapes. From the Basic shapes, choose the double-headed arrow.
   - Use the green dot in that double arrow to resize the arrow shaft until it is a very thin line.
   - Type in the double arrow. Your text goes in one of the arrow heads.
   - Leave that double arrow selected.
   - Press the paintbrush, which acts as a Format menu.
   - In Style > Fill, go to the shades of gray. Choose white.
   - In Text > Color, choose black.
2. Connect the two vertical lines:

   - Place a shape above the white double arrow.
   - Place another shape below the white double arrow.
   - Make lines to connect each of those two shapes to the white double arrow. The lines connect to the white double arrow on its very thin arrow shaft.

   I had to learn how to make connections between shapes:

   - Add a curve to the page.
   - Drag each end of the curve until it snaps to one of your shapes.
   - Now you can format the curve's connection style as "Straight".
3. Rotate the connection point:

   - Place two separated fingertips on the white double arrow. Turn the double arrow by rotating the two fingertips around a spot between them.
   - Move the shapes until each of their lines are connected to the arrow shaft again.